# Unable to to generate URL from named Route in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, url-routing

I'm getting the exception:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "allPrograms" as such route does not exist.").

Thing is... the route does exist:

```
namespace Admin\Bundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class ProgramController extends AdminController  {
    private $config;
    private $sqlConnection;
    private $programMysqlDAO;
    ...
    /**
     * @Route("/admin/program", name="allPrograms")
     *
     * This will only trigger if there's no index.php
     * @return Response
     */
    public function indexAction()  {
        //do stuff.
    }
    ...
}
```

Here's the relevant portion of the twig template that calls it:

```
<a href="{{ path('allPrograms') }}">
```

I have `use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;` at the top of my code.  I also have the routing for this particular bundle configured in `routing.yml`:

```
admin:
    resource: "@AdminBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /
```

here's what `app/console debug:router` shows:

```
  Name                                                 Method   Scheme   Host   Path
 ---------------------------------------------------- -------- -------- ------ ----------------------------------------------
  _wdt                                                 ANY      ANY      ANY    /_wdt/{token}
  _profiler_home                                       ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/
  _profiler_search                                     ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/search
  _profiler_search_bar                                 ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/search_bar
  _profiler_info                                       ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/info/{about}
  _profiler_phpinfo                                    ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/phpinfo
  _profiler_search_results                             ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/search/results
  _profiler                                            ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}
  _profiler_router                                     ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/router
  _profiler_exception                                  ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/exception
  _profiler_exception_css                              ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/exception.css
  _twig_error_test                                     ANY      ANY      ANY    /_error/{code}.{_format}
  admin__default_index                                 ANY      ANY      ANY    /
  config                                               ANY      ANY      ANY    /admin/config
  configIndex                                          ANY      ANY      ANY    /admin/config/{program}
  admin__program_create                                POST     ANY      ANY    /admin/program
  admin__program_edit                                  PUT      ANY      ANY    /admin/program
  admin__program_delete                                DELETE   ANY      ANY    /admin/program
  admin__program_index                                 ANY      ANY      ANY    /admin/program
  queue_index                                          GET      ANY      ANY    /admin/queue
```

As you can see, I have other named routes defined, which work properly.  My router debug also shows the route in question `/admin/program method:Any`, but does not show the name.

I've tried:
    Clearing / warming the cache:
    php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
    php app/console cache:clear --env=dev
    php app/console cache:clear
    php app/console cache:warmup --env=prod --no-debug

```
Removing composer vendor and:
composer -vvv update

Recreating composer autoload:
composer -vvv dump-autoload -o
```

Does anyone have any ideas why my named route is not being found in Symfony?

**UPDATE**
I should have mentioned, I already tried using `admin__program_index` in my twig template... and, yes, it does work.  However, I want to use my named route and I have no idea why it's not working.

I'm using named routes in other controllers:

```
namespace Admin\Bundle\Controller;

use ...

class ConfigController extends AdminController  {
    /**
     * @Route("/admin/config", name="config")
     * @return Response
     */
    public function indexAction()  {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

This named route works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Here your route is logically for example:

`admin__program_index`  is for request `ANY`    `/admin/program`

`admin__program_edit`   is for request `PUT`    `/admin/program`

`admin__program_create` is for request `POST`   `/admin/program`

`admin__program_delete` is for request `DELETE` `/admin/program`

**If you can't understand you can run command:**

`app/console debug:router --show-controllers`

This is command show `routes` with `Controllers`

**Try change** `<a href="{{ path('allPrograms') }}">` **to** `<a href="{{ path('admin__program_index') }}">`

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Imanali...  I should have mentioned that I tried `admin__program_index`, and it does work.  Thing is, I'm using other named routes (different controller, same bundle / namespace) and they do work.